# What design decisions can I make today, that would make a migration to Azure and Azure Tables easier later?

Tags: azure

I'm rebuilding an application from the ground up.  At some point in the future...not sure if it's near or far yet, I'd like to move it to Azure.  What decisions can I make today, that will make that migration easier.

I'm going to be dealing with large amounts of data, and like the idea of Azure Tables...are there some specific persistance choices I can make now that will mimick Azure Tables so that when the time comes the pain of migration will be lessened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good place to start is the [Windows Azure Guidance](http://wag.codeplex.com/)

If you want to use Azure Tables eventually, you could design your database where all tables are a primary key, plus a field with XML data.

Answer (score 1):

I would advise to plan along the lines of almost-infinitely scalable solutions (see [Pat Helland's](http://abdullin.com/wiki/pat-helland.html) paper on Life beyond distributed transactions) and the [CQRS approach](http://abdullin.com/cqrs/) in general. This way you'll be able to avoid common pitfalls of the distributed apps generally and Azure table storage peculiarities.

This really helps us to work with Azure and Cloud Computing at [Lokad](http://www.lokad.com/Default.aspx) (data-sets are quite large plus various levels of scalability are needed).